# Jquery .submit() event does not work with ASP.net pages?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Just wondering about jQuery and ASP.Net. I have a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/deanparkr/brmLz9m9/

When the ok button is pressed the form is submitted to ViewCalls.aspx.

The code works fine on a Classic ASP page, but if I move it into ASP.Net, nothing happens. It seems as though it cannot bind the submit event to a form. But that's a guess, as nothing is reported in Chrome's JS inspector.

Is there any reason why .submit() does not work with ASP.Net pages? The code is:

```
$(function () {
$('#AssignCall').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    show: "fade",
    hide: "fade",
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function () {
            $("#AssignCallForm").submit();
            //$(this).dialog("close");
        },
            "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

});

```
<div id="AssignCall" title="Assign Call" style="display:none;">
    <form id="AssignCallForm" method="post" action="ViewCalls.aspx"> <span id="ctl00_MainContent_AssignTo">Assign to:</span>

        <select name="ctl00$MainContent$AssignToDropDown" id="ctl00_MainContent_AssignToDropDown">
            <option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
            <option value="test1">Test1</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$MainContent$Action" id="ctl00_MainContent_Action" value="AssignCall" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To run server side code you will probably have to do something like this:

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
$('#AssignCall').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    show: "fade",
    hide: "fade",
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function () {
            $("#button").click();
            //$(this).dialog("close");
        }, 
            "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:button runat="server" id="button" ClientIdMode="static" OnClick="ButtonClick" />
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //server side stuff
}
```

OR

You can omit the OnClick event to simply submit the form...

EDIT:

Made the changes to your [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/brmLz9m9/1/)

Comment: Hi, I have set the Ok function to:

`$("#button").click();`

And the input button to:

`<input type="submit" id="button" onclick="document.AssignCallForm.submit()" style="display:none;" />`

However, I then get a JS error "Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined"

Comment: Are you attempting to call the `submit()` event in the onclick handler? That shouldn't be necessary. If the page is an `.aspx` then what you need to do is add the `<asp:button...` code I added above to your page. You can 'not include' the `OnClick` if you simply want it to submit the form without running any custom methods server-side.

Comment: I have discovered that by adding:

'appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));'

To the jQuery the form now submits on all browsers except for IE8 - so some progress :). 

Looks like an compatibility issue between ASP.Net postback JS and jQuery.